# Generate X509 from .cer file inside same project

Tags: visual-studio-2008, file

```
m_X509Certificate = X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile("Test.cer")
```

Says it can't find the file. But it's in the same directory as the project. Is my path wrong?

Comment: What kind of project is this?  You could be running from inside the bin folder.  Why not print out what the current path is?

Comment: You were right. If I use current I can nav to it. Post as an answer and ill accept :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use current path and then append file name.